# Image skew bug in Chrome only

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have an image with height 100% and width auto. It should always be square and never skewed. If you resize your browser to make the website less tall, the image gets skewed. While skewed you can open the inspector and uncheck height 100% then re-check it and the image will snap back to square.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id=outer style='height:100vh'>
            <div style='height:50%'>
                <img style='height:100%;' src='https://i.pinimg.com/236x/0f/9a/36/0f9a36457c046fe12c2c69ad60a3e737--creative-thinking-texture.jpg' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/auey41fd/

This is really messing up my site for chrome users. Does anyone know a good work around? It doesn't only happen when the user resizes the browser. Any time the outer container becomes less tall, the images inside get skewed. It's not specific to using vh units. Everything works fine in firefox and IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug was confirmed by Chromium.
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=773445#c16
After over a year of not trying to fix it they recoded something and inadvertently fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Change `height` to `min-height`. That should fix your issue.

Comment: On the image? nope didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Put `display: flex;` on the image so it stays the same.